# UNAVAILABLE_RECORDTYPE_EXCEPTION, Unable to find default record type: [] *Record Owner

Tags: lightning, community, salesforcedx, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

When I try to convert lead It says "Error: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNAVAILABLE_RECORDTYPE_EXCEPTION, Unable to find default record type: []"
Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is similar to this one https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093fPIAQ

so try this: go to Setup -> Manager Users -> Profiles, then select your profile type. From there, scroll all the way down to the Record Type Settings section and under the Standard Record Type Settings sub-section, Go to the Leads field and ensure that there are values there. If not, you'll need to click Edit and assign a default.

Comment: Actually, Already did that but issue is not resolved