# Convert Lead to Patient unavailable default record type error for partner community user

Tags: profile, administration, lead-conversion, health-cloud

When a partner community user tries to convert a Lead to a Person Account from Experience Cloud getting this error. But for system admin user Lead to patient conversion working fine.

We are using Salesforce provided Lead to patient Flows for converting Lead to Patient. It has apex action which is part of Health Cloud package and this package access also provided to partner community user.

> An Apex error occurred: System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNAVAILABLE_RECORDTYPE_EXCEPTION, Unable to find default record type: []

I have checked: the user has default record type for both Lead and Account object and we are using Salesforce default Lead to patient conversion Flow. How to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000DHyMQAW

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UNAVAILABLE\_RECORDTYPE\_EXCEPTION, Unable to find default record type: \[\] \*Record Owner](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/340162/unavailable-recordtype-exception-unable-to-find-default-record-type-record)

Comment: I have given record type access for the user profile already but still getting same issue.